# Cypress visit() fails: TypeError: Invalid character in header content ["cookie"]

Tags: cypress

I understand that the error reason is an invalid character inside a cookie, but in my case I prefer to find an workaround without fixing the way how the cookies are saved. The error stack trace is:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR] [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["cookie"]
    at ClientRequest.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:467:3)
    at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:222:14)
    at Object.request (https.js:309:10)
    at Request.start (C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\request\request.js:751:32)
    at Request.end (C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\request\request.js:1507:10)
    at end (C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\request\request.js:564:14)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\Cypress\Cache\4.0.0\Cypress\resources\app\packages\server\node_modules\request\request.js:578:7)
    at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:439:21)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to fix the error would be to escape the cookies when they are saved by the app. But, if you cannot fix the app code for some reason, the workaround might be to [override](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Overwrite-Existing-Commands) `visit()` command and escape the invalid cookies at the end of each request:

```js
Cypress.Commands.overwrite('visit', (originalFn, ...args) => {
  const [ url, options ] = (() => {
    if (typeof args[0] === 'object') {
      const { url, ...options } = args[0];
      return [ url, options ];
    } else {
      return args;
    }
  })();

  if (options && options.__original) {
    return originalFn(url, options);
  } else {
    escapeCookie("firstInvalidCookie");
    escapeCookie("secondInvalidCookie");

    return cy.visit(url, {
      ...options,
      __original: true
    });
  }
});

function escapeCookie(name) {
  return cy.getCookie(name, { log: false }).then(cookie => {
    cy.clearCookie(name, { log: false });

    if (cookie) {
      cy.setCookie(name, encodeURIComponent(cookie.value), {
        domain: 'my.domain.com',
        log: false
      });
    }
  });
}
```